# return object with lambda in java

Tags: java, lambda, return

how do I return an object using lambda in java?
I try using  `objeto = (Runnable[] obj, int pos) -> {obj[pos++]};` in `main()` but not work.

is it possible to return object `obj[pos]` using lambda inside inst() function?

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Runna{
    public static Runnable inst(Runnable[] obj, int pos){
        return obj[pos];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with what you have?

Comment: It's very unclear what you want.  The code you've shown us compiles.

Comment: I just need to return this object `obj[pos]` using a lambda expression, but I've already tried using lambda in various ways and with no success.

Comment: Why would you want to when you can just do `Runnable r  = obj[pos];`?  It doesn't makes sense (at least to me)  to pass an array and index to a static method so you can retrieve a value from the array using the index.

Comment: I agree with you, it doesn't make any sense.
But I'm just following a requirement imposed on me of returning a `Runnable` object from a method using a lambda expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do this.

```
Runnable[] array = new Runnable[10]; // some array filled with Runnables.
BiFunction<Runnable[],  Integer, Runnable> lookup = (arr, i) -> arr[i];
Runnable foo = lookup.apply(array, 3);
```

Now you can do `foo.run();`

You needed a `BiFunction` to accept two disparate arguments and return a third.

Comment: Worked perfectly.
I don't know how BiFunction works, but I'll research about it

Comment: It's just another functional interface that takes two arguments  (compare to Function<T,R> which takes one argument).  Any interface that has a single abstract method is a functional interface. (interface method signatures are implicitly abstract).